# If we give an MBR, Is there any way to get the region in the MBR from Google maps API?

Tags: google-maps

I'm writing an Android app. I'll need to find out the part of the map that falls under the MBR that is constructed using 2 given points.

Is this possible through Google Maps API? please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Bharat

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

this is what `fitBounds` is for:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(35, 10)); // point 1
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(40, 15)); // point 2
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jhTLL/